# Being a Good Webmaster is so hard?

Tags: business, features

How do you define a good Webmaster ?

Because there are a lot of people can say "I'm a webmaster". And i say them "Yes you can use a lot tools, software etc. but this doesn't make you a Webmaster"..

What is the features of a Good Webmaster? Is it so hard to be?

What do you think about that?

Comment: Flagging for wiki status. There's no "answer" to this.

Comment: This does not meet the criteria for community wiki

Answer (score 2):

The definition of webmaster has changed quite a bit in the last 15 or so years. It used to be somebody that runs a website, knows a bit of html etc.

However now I think the definition (although it is mainly opinions, not set in stone) consists of:

- In charge of a website's daily progress. They may have a boss and they may have their own team (unlike before where generally less people would work on a website together)
- Knows and uses tools and languages such as FTP, HTML, CSS, JS, CMS software etc.
- Delegates the work around the team
- The person who is contacted in regards to the website

Some people even argue that webmaster is a defunct position, however it is still on many job titles.

Basically, a webmaster is a manager with skills based on website development, design and content management. They do not need to be a master at any one of these, more of a "Jack Of All Trades Master Of Management" kind of thing.

I hope that helps, it was my first answer on this site!

Shane